# Estimates on number of observations and iterations depending on number of states, when applying the Baum-Welch algorithm to HMMs

Tags: st.statistics, hidden-markov-models

Are there papers estimating how many observations $\mathcal{O}$ and how many random initializations $\ell$ one needs, to get an arbitrary good agreement between the model $\lambda = (\pi,A,B)$ that generated $\mathcal{O}$, and $\tilde{\lambda} = (\tilde{\pi},\tilde{A},\tilde{B})$, where $\tilde{\lambda}$ is the output from the Baum-Welch algorithm? Specifically, let $\pi$ be the initial distribution, $A$ the transition-matrix and $B$ the emission-matrix. Then how does the number of states $N$ affects  how large $|\mathcal{O}|$ and $\ell$ one needs to say that $\hat{\pi} = \begin{pmatrix} |\pi_1 - \tilde{\pi}_1| & \ldots & |\pi_N - \tilde{\pi}_N| \end{pmatrix}$,

$\hat{A} = \begin{pmatrix} |A_{11}-\tilde{A}_{11}| & \ldots & |A_{1N}-\tilde{A}_{1N}| \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ |A_{N1}-\tilde{A}_{N1}| & \ldots & |A_{NN}-\tilde{A}_{NN}| \end{pmatrix}$

and

$\hat{B} = \begin{pmatrix} |B_{11}-\tilde{B}_{11}| & \ldots & |B_{1M}-\tilde{B}_{1M}| \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ |B_{N1}-\tilde{B}_{N1}| & \ldots & |B_{NM}-\tilde{B}_{NM}| \end{pmatrix}$

are such that $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N} \hat{\pi}_{j} < \epsilon$, $\sum\limits_{i,j = 1}^{N} \hat{A}_{ij} < \epsilon$ and $\sum\limits_{i,j} \hat{B}_{ij} < \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}$.

I am not neccessarily looking for a mathematical proof, I would be glad even for general guidelines (I believe one would say "heuristics"), although of course a proof would be nice.

Edit: This submission to arxiv seem relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08269.